# VPN on Fedora Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, software-rec, vpn

I'm looking to install and setup a VPN on my Linux installation which is Fedora 14.  At the moment the only one I know of is OpenVPN but I'm wondering if this the best option for Fedora or if Fedora offers other options that are better?

EDIT:  Definitely looking for free solutions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fedora also packages [Openswan](http://www.openswan.org/), which has a free IPsec implementation that you can use for a VPN.

Comment: IPsec?  What is this?

Comment: Is Openswan better for VPN?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec
One advantage of using Openswan and IPSec is that the kernel does a lot of the hard work managing the IPSec connection, while OpenVPN uses SSL tunnels in user space.

Comment: The disadvantage of Openswan is it's more complex to set up.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!  It sounds like its worth the time it would take to learn and set up.

Answer (score 1):

I use VPN setups extensively. I suggest OpenVPN rather then IPsec implementations. OpenVPN has much more features and possibilities.
Markus Feilner - OpenVPN is a great book to learn.

Comment: jsbillings suggested that IPsec was advantageous because the kernal was doing much of the work rather than relying on ssl... do you disagree? why?

Comment: IPsec implementations are not well standarized, and because of kernel space, it's implementation is kernel dependent, therefore OS dependent. OpenVPN is a free open solution, you can count on in every environment. It has many features, NAT support, and so on. Many things what can be handy, if you build the VPN solution on OpenVPN. Mikrotik routers support it, if you need hardware router. http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/339-why-ssl-vpn.html

Answer (score -2):

OpenVPN FTW!!!

Tested and working flawlessly! Low resources needed, highly scalable, very secure... just AWESOME!!